# If questions about general health and diet issues are not allowed, does it make sense to keep the "health" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are some questions that are tagged [health](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health), but the FAQ clearly states that questions about general health and diet issues should not be asked on *Seasoned Advice*.

Does the tag have a purpose, or is it only used to catch possible off-topic questions? If the purpose is the latter, should not a description saying "If you are asking a question that uses this tag, the question being asked is probably off-topic on this site." be added to the tag wiki?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the tag has no purpose; it's an artifact of the public beta period from a long time ago and we just haven't gotten around to closing/deleting/retagging all the [health](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health) questions.

I'm not sure if adding a wiki will really help, as several people continue to use the [recipe](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recipe) and [ingredients](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ingredients) tag even though their wikis clearly say not to use them.  But if somebody would like to do that, then I suppose it can't really hurt.

Comment: The tag wiki could be added, if the tag is going to be kept. Would not it better to remove that tag from the questions, and avoid it gets added again?

Comment: I prefer not to waste time and front-page space retagging questions that should actually be closed.  If there's a legitimate question that's just poorly-tagged with [health], by all means, please retag; otherwise, flag it or (for anyone reading this who has the rep) vote to close/delete.

Comment: we're trying to give the tag wiki excerpt more exposure in asking.. improvements coming in that area.

Comment: I guess @Jeff was referring to the new field for adding tags to questions, which shows the excerpt of the tag, when one exists.